# get the value of an embedded form variable to use in service task

Tags: java, spring-boot, bpmn, camunda-modeler

I'm using embedded form in camunda modeler, and I don't know how to get the value of the form variables to use in a service task

I tried using the id of the input task but it didn't seem to be working

Comment: Can you please provide your code?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was `cam-variable-name="firstName"` `cam-variable-type="String"`, so first name is the variable name that the task can use to get the value.